# Killing ansi-term says: "... has a running process"

Tags: ansi-term

Whenever I kill an ansi-term buffer I have to confirm due to the fact of:
"ansi-term has a running process; kill it ?", (even if nothing is running btw).

How could I have Emacs killing the term without requiring this confirmation regardless of active processes.

Thanks !

Comment: Assuming you're running a shell in the terminal, the "running process" is *the shell itself*. If you exit your shell (typically `C-d` or `exit`) before killing the ansi-term buffer, it will not ask you this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
(defun set-no-process-query-on-exit ()
  (let ((proc (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))))
    (when (processp proc)
      (set-process-query-on-exit-flag proc nil))))

(add-hook 'term-exec-hook 'set-no-process-query-on-exit)
```

Comment: You're awesome. It works !

Comment: this is really cool and works for eshell, ansi-term, term etc but strangley not for 'shell'. any clue why?